# cefsharp change audio source name

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I have a little c# winforms app, that plays some youtube videos. To play them, i'm using cefsharp because the winforms browser (IE9) doesn't support it.
everything is working fine, but i'd like to change the audio source name displayed in the volume mixer to the name of the app. (Currently it is "CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess")
here's the code i'm using to initialize the browser object

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser Browser;

    public void InitializeChromium(string url, string cachepath)
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        // Initialize cef with the provided settings
        settings.CachePath = cachepath;
        //Handle cookies, such as yt login
        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(cachepath, "Extensions")))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(cachepath, "Extensions"));
        }

        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        // Create a browser component
        Browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url);
        // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.

        this.Controls.Add(Browser);
        Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Browser.AddressChanged += Browser_AddressChanged;
        Browser.TitleChanged += Browser_TitleChanged;
        KeyDown += Browser_KeyDown;
    }
```

It is possible?
if yes, do i need to use some special arguments?
thanks in advice.

Comment: Chromium uses a multiple process model, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#processes for background. At a guess it's picking up the assembly title https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/79/CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs Do you use any of the features related to JavaScript Binding or JavaScript evaluation?  You can use your own exe as the browser sub process with a bit of work.  I'm only guessing here that it's the title. You can do your own research to see how the mixer detects the name of the process playing audio.

Comment: ok so i found a solution. i'll recompile CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe using the icon of my program and i'll edit the code by adding a line that changes the title.

Comment: Recompiling the exe is not recommended,  create your own distinct exe. Antivirus software will see your modified version as being slightly different which will likely cause you problems.